# how to return null composite objects in mql

Tags: javascript, freebase, mql

I have been working on a simple [calorie counter](http://wholcomb.github.io/calorie_counter/) using freebase. When I am [querying for a recipe](http://tinyurl.com/m2aucbh) I am not getting all the entries returned.

My query is:

```
[{
  "id": "/m/0e cvb9k7",
  "name": null,
  "/food/recipe/ingredients": [{
    "id": null,
    "ingredient": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null,
      "/food/food/energy": null
    },
    "unit": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null
    },
    "quantity": null
  }]
}]
```

For example, in the gumbo recipe there are ingredients like onions or peppers where unit is null. Those are not returned by this query. How do I write a query that will return all the ingredients, including the ones with null units?

I tried:

```
"unit|=": [
  null,
 {
    "id": null,
    "name": null
  }
]
```

This gave me an error `Comparison operator |= takes a non-empty list of values`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "optional": true to that subquery viz

```
[{
  "id": "/m/0e cvb9k7",
  "name": null,
  "/food/recipe/ingredients": [{
    "id": null,
    "ingredient": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null,
      "/food/food/energy": null
    },
    "unit": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null
      "optional":true
    },
    "quantity": null
  }]
}]
```